# How to insert the content of my txt file in a widget with Python 2.7 on visual studio code?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have to create a program that allows me to read a .txt file that already exists and insert the content of that file in a text widget. Can someone help me ?

```py
from Tkinter import *

fenetre = Tk()
champ_label = Label(fenetre, text="titres incorrectes")
champ_label.pack()
ligne_texte = Text(fenetre)
ligne_texte.pack()
fenetre.mainloop()
```

This is my text widget

Comment: `open(), read(), close()`

Comment: and `ligne_texte.insert("end", text_from_file)` - see [Text](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('yourfile', 'r') as myfile:
  yourtext= myfile.read()
ligne_texte.insert(END, yourtext)
```

If the text is too long, you may have problems displaying the whole text. Maybe you should try a scrollbar in the textbox.

Comment: thank you, i just put it in but it tells me : <<<NameError: name 'ligne_texte' is not defined>>>           what do i do?

Comment: That menas you haven't defined your _ligne_texte_ variable correctly. Have you tried to do _ligne_texte.insert(END, 'sample text')_ right after _ligne_texte = Text(fenetre)_ ?

Comment: i tried but then it tells me: <<<NameError: name 'text' is not defined>>>

Comment: You seems to lack the basic understanding on how python or tkinter works. I suggest you to go through some tutorials like [effbot](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-hello-tkinter.htm).

Answer (score 0):

This code here should work:

```py
from Tkinter import *

fenetre = Tk()
champ_label = Label(fenetre, text="titres incorrectes")
champ_label.pack()
ligne_texte = Text(fenetre)
ligne_texte.pack()
ligne_texte.insert(END, open('file.txt', 'r').read())
fenetre.mainloop()
```

Here is what it brings up:
[image: What the code brings up.]

Hope this helps.